# <asp:Label> how use it with linq to SQL & Xhtml5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, linq, count

It is my WebForm Page how to use the `<asp:Label>`.
below is My C# code:

```
int compteurtotal2016Bg =(from Tickets in context.Tickets where Tickets.dateStart.Year == 2016 && Tickets.state == Helper.State.Done select Tickets).Count();
try { } catch { }
this.labelNbBg2016.Text += compteurtotal2016Bg.ToString();
```

below is My Html Code :

```
<asp:Label ID ="labelNBSgac2016" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I don't know how to do.

Comment: Leaving weird try/catch aside, this looks fine. What is your problem?

Comment: My Label on Html is not recognize and i can't use it

Comment: Is there really a space between `ID` and `=` in your Label markup? If so, please remove it.

Comment: Where is that C# code? It needs to be in the codebehind of that page, to see the Label.

Comment: hi Hans for you're two comment Thanks But 1:i remove space but it's same 2: i've already a code behind with my c# page